# How to debug a mobile safari crash?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I'm developing a browser-based mobile app built on top of jQuery Mobile, and some recent change I made is now causing safari to consistently crash on load -- this is reliably reproducible on at least two different iphones.

Since the information available is way too vague to actually figure out what is causing the crash, my question isn't so much "what's going wrong?" as it is "how would you go about debugging a safari crash?" -- I'm already working on bisecting my changes until I strike gold, but that's not always a practical approach.

EDIT: Should've clarified that the debug console doesn't produce any useful information (there are no unexpected console messages), and that the error, whatever it may be, doesn't manifest itself on a desktop browser. Also, by crash I mean the browser completely locks up and I can't get it to a usable state except by explicitly killing it from the  task manager and restarting it.

Comment: In my case it is an "inspectord" "highwater" error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a iOS device is synced with iTunes (OSX) crash logs can be found at
**~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/**

There might be some useful info there although mostly MobileSafari crashes are caused on account of low memory. Optimization optimization optimization

Comment: What about windows? Is there any way to get the logs on a windows machine?

Comment: For windows checkout `\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\<device name>`

Answer (score 3):

After syncing with iTunes find the crash logs at `CrashReporter/MobileDevice/[Your_Device_Name]`

From the device hit up `General -> About -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostic & Usage Data` , but note there may be no way to sort this list by time, so it gets kinda random.

For full details reference https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/crash/ and http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/retrieving-crash-reports-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TestFlight, this might help you https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devc8ced2ea3

Go to XCode and Choose Window > Organizer, and click Crashes

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Here are some things you can do:

- [Turn on the Debug Console in Mobile Safari](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/14447/step-by-step-turn-on-the-iphone-ipads-web-debugging-console/)
- [Debug your webpage in Chrome with Chrome Developer Tools (Video)](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/videos.html)

Comment: Thanks, but neither helped -- Chrome is my primary development environment and I'm quite fond of its debugger, but, alas, it cannot find bugs that don't trigger in chrome. :(

Comment: Could you provide a link to the webapp? so I could test on my device

Comment: Afraid I can't make it available on an outwards facing server right now.